# What does "arroz atollado" mean?

Tags: definiciones, comida, colombia

The Colombian dish of [*arroz atollado*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arroz_atollado).

I know what "arroz" means, but I haven't been able to find what the second part "atollado" is supposed to mean.

Comment: hahaha, I'm a native spanish, and I don't know... is a slang that has meanning just in some region, of course it has literal meaning arroz atascado, arroz con problemas, but it hasn't real meanning, at least nor for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this web about Colombian gastronomy](http://gastrolombia.jimdo.com/historias/platos-regionales/arroz-atollado/) you can learn the etymology of *atollado* in this context.

> El arroz atollado debe su nombre a la receta de la Costa Pacifica que originalmente era elaborada con TOYO, un tiburón joven muy apreciado por los guapireños, que suelen comprarlo ahumado en los mercados.

So it seems that originally the recipe used "toyo" (also spelled as [*tollo*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollo_%28pescado%29)) a kind of shark. From the name of this shark the word *"atollado"* evolved (meaning "with toyo"). It seems that the current preparation has not that much in common with the original recipe (being more like *paella* or *arroz con pollo*) but the name has persisted.

Thus, *arroz atollado* means something like *arroz con tollo* (rice with *toyo*) or "*sharked* rice"/ "*Toyed* rice".